# Hakyll tutorial goes wrong

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, hakyll

I am following the Hakyll tutorial as in this https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/tutorials/01-installation.html.

But it seems that something is wrong and I can't tell what it is. When I run 'stack init' I get this message.

```
Looking for .cabal or package.yaml files to use to init the project.
Using cabal packages:
- ./

Selecting the best among 16 snapshots...

* Partially matches lts-14.16
    hakyll not found
        - ourblog-com requires ==4.13.*

* Partially matches nightly-2019-11-25
    hakyll not found
        - ourblog-com requires ==4.13.*

* Partially matches lts-13.30
    hakyll not found
        - ourblog-com requires ==4.13.*

* Partially matches lts-12.26
    hakyll version 4.12.4.0 found
        - ourblog-com requires ==4.13.*

* Partially matches lts-11.22
    hakyll version 4.12.3.0 found
        - ourblog-com requires ==4.13.*

* Partially matches lts-10.10
    hakyll version 4.10.0.0 found
        - ourblog-com requires ==4.13.*

* Partially matches lts-9.21
    hakyll version 4.9.8.0 found
        - ourblog-com requires ==4.13.*

* Partially matches lts-8.24
    hakyll version 4.9.7.0 found
        - ourblog-com requires ==4.13.*

* Partially matches lts-7.24
    hakyll not found
        - ourblog-com requires ==4.13.*

* Partially matches lts-6.35
    hakyll version 4.8.3.2 found
        - ourblog-com requires ==4.13.*

...

* Partially matches lts-0.7
    hakyll not found
        - ourblog-com requires ==4.13.*

Selected resolver: lts-14.16
Resolver 'lts-14.16' does not have all the packages to match your requirements.
    hakyll not found
        - ourblog-com requires ==4.13.*

This may be resolved by:
    - Using '--omit-packages' to exclude mismatching package(s).
    - Using '--resolver' to specify a matching snapshot/resolver
```

My path seems correctly included. Why is this happening?

Comment: Selected resolver: lts-14.16
Resolver 'lts-14.16' does not have all the packages to match your requirements.
    hakyll not found
        - ourblog-com requires ==4.13.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the Hakyll maintainers haven't kept it up to date in the Stack respository.  After creating the `my-site` directory, instead of running `stack init`, create a `stack.yaml` file manually that contains the lines:

```
resolver: lts-14.16
packages:
- .
extra-deps:
- hakyll-4.13.0.1
```

Then run `stack build`, etc. as directed.  That seems to work.

Comment: I just tried this and got `hakyll-4.13.0.1 from stack configuration does not match ==4.12.*  (latest matching version is 4.12.5.2)`

Comment: This suggests your `my-site.cabal` file contains the dependency `hakyll == 4.12.*`, but when I create a fresh site with the current version of `hakyll-init`, my copy of `my-site.cabal` contains the up-to-date dependency `hakyll == 4.13.*`.  Maybe try to re-run `stack install hakyll` to make sure you have the most recent version and then double-check that you're running the newly installed `hakyll-init` to create your site, and not some stale copy.